# Улыбнулась - как именно?

Tags: стилистика

Говорят "мимолетная улыбка" . А "она ему улыбнулась" - как? Мимолетно?:) Или вообще подходящего наречия нет, и надо менять всю конструкцию текста?

Comment: Ошиблась с меткой. Вопрос как раз по стилистике.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мимолетная улыбка - та, которая "мимо пролетела", то есть непроизвольно возникла и так же исчезла, не осознаваемая самим улыбающимся. Поэтому нельзя произвольно, сознательно "мимолетно улыбнуться".

Улыбаться можно: приветливо, загадочно, радостно, добродушно, лукаво, хитро, насмешливо, презрительно, ласково, по-доброму...

Смотрите словари: толковый, синонимов, сочетаемости слов русского языка.

Answer (score 1):

Удивительно, но мимолётная улыбка существует. О ней можно прочитать в словаре:

1) General subject: transient smile
2) Makarov: a wisp of a smile, flash, wisp of a smile

В самых разных прозаических и поэтических текстах тоже можно встретить мимолетную улыбку:

"Мой посланный стоял еще перед Огаревым, когда офицер вошел; они узнали друг друга, глаза их встретились, и мимолетная улыбка осветила черты офицера".[Н.А. Тучкова-Огарева. Воспоминания (1890)]

"Мимолетная улыбка скользнула по губам барона: - И как же он умер? - Он бросился спасать своих любимцев из охотничьего выезда, и сам сгорел".

"Хлоя мимолетно улыбнулась. - Так дела не делаются".

Comment: София, вопрос был не о мимолетной улыбке, а о "мимолетно улыбнуться". Толковый словарь Кузнецова фиксирует "мимолетно улыбнуться, встретиться, поздороваться". В Нацкорпусе аж 2 случая употребления. Но все равно звучит странно.

Comment: Тат,а что именно вас смущает? Мимолетно улыбнуться - это не та улыбка, которая пролетела мимо,а быстрая,незначительная,та которая длится не долго.

Answer (score 0):

Можно и мимолетно. Это уже вопрос стиля, а не грамматики.

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае согласование, а втором - примыкание.

Answer (score 0):

Также можно сказать "улыбнулась украдкой".